# Unable to deploy MySQL on Redhat Openshift

Tags: mysql, openshift

I am unable to deploy MySQL on Redhat openshift. My pod keep going into CrashLoopBackOff. From the error, I don't understand what is the issue because it states that initializing of server in progress as process and after that, it directly goes into shutdown state. Need to understand what is actually happening.

Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-wordpress-deployment
  namespace: wordpress-website
  labels:
    app: mysql-wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql-wordpress
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql-wordpress
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-local-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: local-mysql-pvc
      containers:
        - name: mysql-container
          image: mysql
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          port:
            - containerPorts: 3306
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-pass
                  key: pass
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-local-pv
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
```

PersistentVolume.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-mysql-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: ibmc-block-bronze
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: "20Gi"
  hostPath:
    path: /tmp/data/
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
```

PersistentVolumeClaim.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: local-mysql-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

Error Logs

```
Initializing database
mysqld: Can't create directory '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno 17 - File exists)
2019-08-18T10:16:22.005955Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-08-18T10:16:22.006063Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) initializing of server in progress as process 17
2019-08-18T10:16:22.008464Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2019-08-18T10:16:22.008504Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-08-18T10:16:22.008970Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: `The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.`. I'd say there's something wrong with that directory. Check permissions, check to make sure it's empty, check that is mounted correctly. You can scale down you Deployment to 0 replicas and then run `oc debug <pod name>` in order to get terminal access and look around (scaling to 0 is important since the PVC is RWO)

Comment: Is this your own MySQL image, or the one OpenShift supplies? The one OpenShift supplies is designed to work with the more restrictive default security policies of OpenShift. The one from Docker Hub will likely fail as it requires it be run as root, or as set user. OpenShift will run it as an arbitrary assigned user ID. See https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/why-do-my-applications-run-as-a-random-user-id.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton when I use the MySQL image provided in the openshift documentation I get this error Failed to pull image "registry.redhat.io/rhscl/mysql-57-rhel7": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password. So that's why I am using the image available on docker hub.

Comment: @WillGordon as soon as scale down the deployment to 0, the current pod gets terminated and hence I can't use the command oc debug <pod_name>

Comment: @WillGordon I scaled the deployment to 1 and went into the debug mode but as soon as I try to see the content of the folder I get **ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied** and when I try to change the permission of the dir using command **chmod -R go-w .** I get                                                                      **chmod: changing permissions of '.': Permission denied**
**chmod: cannot read directory '.': Permission denied**

Comment: Run `oc get template/mysql-persistent -n openshift -o yaml` and look at the OpenShift template for deploying MySQL to see what it does. Better still, use that template to deploy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hostPath` is required `privileged` scc to write something to host by pod. 
So you configure `privileged` permission as following steps.

```
# oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged -z default
# oc edit deployment mysql-wordpress-deployment
spec:
...
  template:
  ...
    spec:
    ...
      containers:
      - name: mysql-container
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
```

Basically, `privileged` mode is not recommended as aspect of security, because `privileged` allow to access directly to host resources without any constraints.

I hope it help you.

Comment: Hi I tried the solution, but i am getting this error now **Error creating: pods "mysql-wordpress-deployment-b9f579647-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context constraint: [spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value: true: Privileged containers are not allowed]**

Comment: Are you using OpenShift online ? then you can not `hostPath` type PV, because OpenShift online does not allow accessing host resources. Or what serviceaccount is used by the pod ? You can check the `oc get pod <pod name> -o yaml | grep -i serviceaccountname`. If the serviceaccount is not `default`, then you execute above `oc adm policy` with using serviceaccount again.